# Java checkstyle error ParameterAssignmentCheck

Tags: java, sonarqube, checkstyle

```
private int getChildChildDepth(List<ProjectTask> childProjectTasks, int count)
    {
        for (ProjectTask projectTask : childProjectTasks)
        {
            if (projectTask.getChildTasks().size() > 0)
            {
                count++;
                getChildChildDepth(projectTask.getChildTasks(), count);
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

In above i am getting ParameterAssignmentCheck error at **count++**. I am using recursive function.
**Error:**  Assignment of parameter 'count' is not allowed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I think check style is just warning you that the way in which you are incrementing `count` is not really good style.  You can adjust checkstyle, to make it a warning (rather than an error) or you could try using something like `count += 1`. If the child depth can be large, recursion might not be a goos fit for your problem.

Comment: Your function is not doing what you thing it's doing. All arguments are passed by value, and this means that the recursive call cannot change the value of `count`. What you need is something like `count = getChildChildDepth(projectTask.getChildTasks(), count + 1)`